# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Files.asCharSink

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, guava

I'm getting this error since I updated Android Studio to 9.1 and to gradle 14.+ :

I'm executing the task assembleRelease on my project.
And here is what I got :

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexParisRelease'.
> com.google.common.io.Files.asCharSink(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;[Lcom/google/common/io/FileWriteMode;)Lcom/google/common/io/CharSink;

* Try:        
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dexParisRelease'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Files.asCharSink(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;[Lcom/google/common/io/FileWriteMode;)Lcom/google/common/io/CharSink;
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.getFilesToAdd(AndroidBuilder.java:1429)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1408)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$convertByteCode$4.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.doTaskAction(Dex.groovy:136)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.this$5$doTaskAction(Dex.groovy)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex$this$5$doTaskAction.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.taskAction(Dex.groovy:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 13 more
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use two different versions of Guava at the same time.

Your stacktrace is incomplete so I cannot answer fully. Also, I don't know Android Studio.

But, I can read your stack trace and I see that the class `AndroidBuilder` is trying to access the method [`com.google.common.io.Files.asCharSink`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#asCharSink(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20com.google.common.io.FileWriteMode...)). The method `asCharSink` exists from Guava 14.

Usually the error you get happens when you mess with dependencies.

Given that you see some stack trace components indicating Gradle and that you mention using Gradle, I gather that you get this issue when building using Gradle.

So I don't think that you actually mess with dependencies but rather that you have incompatibilities between your gradle version (requiring Guava 14 or later) and the Guava actually loaded in the classpath of your builder.

So check how Gradle is called and update the Guava version of that tool to 14 or later.

Comment: Thanks sincerely olivier, I edit my post and added all the stacktrace. This may indeed be a gradle problem. The thing is that I don't have any power and the gradle build system. They also just made an update. Also, I have other projects using the same gradle config and using the same Guava version and that does compile. T_T I feel powerless.

Comment: I am having the same issue with another app, and we don't use Guava anywhere at all. In fact, it was building just fine about an hour before, and then suddenly this comes up. Zero changes to the app, the hour difference was my leaving to get dinner. Is there a way to manually override the version of guava referenced in our classpath without adding it to the project dependencies?

FWIW, this happens on plugin versions 0.14.0-0.14.2

Comment: I think this is a bug in the Gradle plugin. I've filed a report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79331

Comment: Yep, it's a bug in Gradle, actually, I solved the problem by simply import one after the other in gradle the libraries that are in the libs folder.